# Listview Cellinsertion in android

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi i have custom listview with textview and edittext.When i click add row button show one row in listview here enter the text and again click add button show another row like this finaly click save button get both textview and edittext values from listview.

i already tried

```
 button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Movi = new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six",
            "seven", "eight", "nine" };
    dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(CustomListView.this, R.layout.list,
            imageArry);
    // add data in contact image adapter
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (itemCount < Movi.length) {
                imageArry.add(new Item(itemCount, Movi, text));
                dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                itemCount++;
            }
        }
    });
```

**Below i add image[image]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Listview and setting an adapter on each and every click, I would suggest you to remove the Listview Completely. Add a TextView and EditText on each click programatically, as follows.

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
// add data in contact image adapter
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (itemCount < Movi.length) {
            imageArry.add(new Item(itemCount, Movi, text));

            // Add TextView
            TextView textView=new TextView();
            textView.setTex(imageArray[itemCount]);
            // Add EditText
            EditText editText=new EditText();

            // Add both to root layout

            parentLayout.addView(textView);
            parentLayout.addView(editText);
            itemCount++;
        }
    }
});
```

Where parentLayout is your root layout of the activity, which you have to assign in onCreate(). For example,

LinearLayout parentLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are adding new item to imageArray, that insertion should be reflected in CustomImageAdapter class. So, after adding item to imageArray, assign this imageArray to CustomImageAdapter imageArray property.

```
public Class CustomImageAdapter {
    Context context;
    int layoutId;
    List<Item> imageArray;

      public CustomImageAdapter(Context context, int layoutId, List<Item> imageArray) {
          this.context = context;
          this.layoutId = layoutId;
          this.imageArray = imageArray;
      }
      public SetImageArray(List<Item> imageArray) {
          this.imageArray = imageArray;
      }

 }
```

You should call **SetImageArray** before calling ***adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()*** method. This is not necessary to set the adapter each time when you are inserting something to already assigned adapter.

Hope this helps...